# Comparison of elements within a same list in list of lists

Tags: python, list

This might sound easy but I am unable to give a proper approach for this.
I want to Delete a whole list from a list of lists that carries two equal elements.
EX

```
[[5,5,5],[5,10,5],[5,10,15],[5,10,10],[5,10,20]]
```

Out

```
[[5,10,15],[5,10,20]]
```

NOTE- The sublist's size is fixed, that is == 3.

Comment: Start by making a function that checks if a list contains two equal elements. Then, once you have that working to satisfaction, you can use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the length of an element as a set to the length of the original list:

```
d = [[5,5,5],[5,10,5],[5,10,15],[5,10,10],[5,10,20]]
new_d = [i for i in d if len(set(i)) == len(i)]
```

Output:

```
[[5, 10, 15], [5, 10, 20]]
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use set and carry out a comparison of elements in a sublist for that purpose.

Comment: @RitikSamaiya Why would you want to not use sets? They are very efficient and probably deliver the best performance.

Comment: @RitikSamaiya I am not sure I understand your latter use case. If you do not want to use sets, `collections.Counter` can be applied to each element and iterated over using `any`, checking if at least one sub element occurs twice. But again, using a `set` is much for efficient that what I just detailed using `collections.Counter`.

Comment: You all are very correct. But I just wanted to carry out the expression using the basic python that's why I was asking so. Intentionally for building a logic for comparisons.

Comment: @RitikSamaiya: Sets are a part of basic Python. If you want to avoid them, you need a better reason than what you have given.

Comment: if you are against using sets, then you could try `[l for l in d if l[0] != l[1] and l[1] != l[2] and l[2] != l[0]]`. more verbose, less pythonic but probably just a little bit faster since a set is not constructed

Answer (score 3):

Can be done by list comprehension, like so -

```
[i for i in my_list if len(set(i)) == len(i)]
```

What we are doing here is we are checking how many unique elements are the in a list of list, by using `set(i)`, if after set, it still contains 3 elements, that means all the elements are unique and we need that list.

If we look at the code and the list -

```
my_list = [[5,5,5],[5,10,5],[5,10,15],[5,10,10],[5,10,20]]
# [i for i in my_list] will get us [5,5,5], [5,10,5] ...
# applying set(i) on, for example first i will give us set([5])
# and len(set([5])) is not equal to len(i)
# therefore O/P will be
O/P = [i for i in my_list if len(set(i)) == len(i)]
#[[5, 10, 15], [5, 10, 20]]
```

Comment: True, can use to compare the `len(i)`, updating